# Consequences of lack of honesty in editorial review

Tags: peer-review

A journal claims to have a policy that if a paper is rejected then any later improved version of the paper is unwelcome.

A quick editorial review happens before the paper is sent to a referee, and rejection often happens then. At that stage, a reviewer wrote of a very short letter saying that I had submitted something like "The corollary to the main proposition only says that if the left side of the equality changes, then so does the right side." That was the *only* thing about the paper that was mentioned in the rejection notice. But the corollary is a short simple sentence and anyone who reads it would know better than to think it says anything like that. Clearly this was not done honestly.

**Here (not elsewhere) is the question:**

What might happen if I emailed every member of the editorial board to ask whether the policy should be considered applicable to cases of a rejection known to result from lack of honesty in the review process?

**End of question**

**PLEASE NOTE: My actual question here is my actual question here.** It seems people often react to things like this by answering questions that are insinuated but not explicit. That may be useful but it's not the same as addressing the actual question.

Comment: Are you a grad student?  Is your paper submitted under only your name?  Are any professors or established academics co-authoring?  Unfortunately, the reality is that politics infects academia also.  We know for certain that lot's of crappy papers from well-known academic authors are published.  And we're nearly as certain that salient and accurate papers from unknown and previously unpublished authors are rejected.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : I've had several longer papers published in the same journal.

Comment: What's your definition of "honest"? Maybe that was honestly what the reviewer (editor?) thought. They may have done this in less time than they should have spent in order to properly appreciate your work, but that wouldn't make it dishonest.

Comment: Re "It seems people often react to things like this by answering questions that are insinuated but not explicit." That may well be correct, however many questions come with implicit assumptions that deserve to be challenged, and sometimes a writer can get as much or more out of having such an assumption challenged as from an answer.

Comment: @Lewian : If someone writes something that it would be irrational for them to write if they had not read the thing they're commenting on, I would consider that dishonest. Saying that a short simple sentence says something that a person who had read it could not think it says is not honest.

Comment: You are underestimating the human ability to misconstrue, missunderstand or simply pay insufficient attention. What would an editor have to gain by lying about your paper? Are you a direct competitor of the editor? Do you challenge  one of the positions they are known for?  (in which case, this would seem a poor choice of journal).  Even if they are being dishonest, in the absence of solid proof, it is in your interests to not accuse someone of lying and therefore jeopardize your chances of getting anything in that journal again.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor

Comment: @IanSudbery : I didn't mean to suggest it was a premeditated lie. Paying insufficient attention and then writing something that requires sufficient attention is what I was calling lack of honesty.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist : I wasn't attributing anything to malice. Dishonesty can happen without malice.

Comment: Please edit the title to actually describe your question.

Comment: No, dishonest is an accusation of deliberate misconduct. Dishonest is commonly understood to involve a someone saying something they know not to be true, and it will be taken that way, even if that is not how you intend it.

Comment: @IanSudbery "that they know not to be true" is not the same as "that they do not know to be true". And the latter is what I had in mind.

Comment: The important thing is that you have no control over how an editor at a journal might interpret "a lack of honesty"/"dishonesty" - and you've seen from the responses here that not everyone shares the same understanding of those words as you have.

Comment: A mistake is usually called a mistake and not a lack of honesty, even if it is both.

Comment: I recommend using words that mean what you are actually trying to say, not some other words that mean something else.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist : But the consequences of a mistake are sometimes different when it is an instance of dishonesty from what they would be when it is not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle

Comment: @BenBolker : Did you have in mind some particular way of applying the information in the linked article?

Comment: My point was just to reinforce the comments by lots of other people here that it doesn't help to use "honesty" in a sense that is going to be misinterpreted by (based on this sample) most of the people receiving your messages, regardless of whether it is technically correct ... my advice (which I know is **not** answering the question you asked) would be to appeal to the editor saying "the reviewer seems to have misconstrued the contents of my paper" (this phrasing is extremely neutral and waffly - intentionally so).

Comment: @BenBolker : So you identify a deficiency in (what you take to be) most people's understanding of what honesty is, which deficiency necessitates communicating with them in a manner suitable to people who lack full understanding. But at some point it will be necessary and appropriate to point out that it actually is a deficiency.

Answer (score 13):

> What might happen if I emailed every member of the editorial board to
> ask whether the policy should be considered applicable to cases of a
> rejection known to result from lack of honesty in the review process?

There is a 99% chance that this would result in the other editors rolling their eyes and muttering something akin to "another bitter author who can't take a rejection" and pressing delete and forgetting about it almost immediately. It doesn't matter if this is not a fair assessment of the situation, it is what they will think.  Particularly as you suggest you don't even want to bring a specific accusation, but rather pose the question to the bored as some kind of hypothetical. Indeed, them forgetting you is probably the best for you, because if they remember you they are likely to approach any future submission with an attitude of "its that crank again".

Except in cases of abuse, bullying or discriminatory behavior, you will always get further by at least pretending to assume good intensions. If you really want to kick up a fuss, you would do much better to start by appealing the decision, directly to the editor you rejected, pointing out patiently, in detail and in a friendly manner why what they said is wrong. If/when that fails, you could try making a complaint to the editor-in-chief, not the editorial board members, but I would still stir clear of making accusations of dishonesty without hard evidence (and in this case, hard evidence is impossible). The complaint should be *specific*, *concrete* and with a request for how you would like to see the mistake remedied (i.e. your paper sent out for review).

Comment: Well, it seems that from this thread I'm learning that some people construe the expression "lack of honesty" to mean malicious lack of honesty or premeditated lack of honesty or a decision to be dishonest in order to serve some purpose. But I never suspected that any of that was at work here.

Comment: Then I'd advise you to be very careful not to give anyone at the journal the impression you believe that there might believe that.

Answer (score 9):

The most likely thing that would happen is **nothing.**. Editors are used to authors complaining about unfair rejections and learn to shrug off such complaints in the vast majority of cases, which I am reasonably certain your situation falls into.

The second most likely thing that would happen (that I think is actually still somewhat likely) is: nothing, but at least some of the people you are emailing will take serious offense at your accusation (explicit, or implied) that the handling editor or reviewer acted dishonestly. You will mark yourself as an unreasonable and difficult person, and this could end up damaging your career in various ways — not immediately, but at some point in the future.

The immediate effect, as I said, would be the same in both scenarios: nothing would happen.

Answer (score 7):

Very likely nothing would happen. Their policy is probably long standing and works well for them in most cases. You might just stir them up to no effect.

I suggest that you submit elsewhere for success. Quite a number of journals, but not all, have such a policy.

Alternatively write back to whoever you corresponded with and suggest that the reader/editor/reviewer
seems to have misinterpreted something. It might have been an honest error, actually.

Comment: Your answer is about what would happen to any resubmission, but more generally what might happen? Assume my inquiry does not identify the paper in question. Might anyone write a rational response proving that they understood what I had written? Might there be reasoned deliberation among the editors followed by a decision on what the policy should be in such a circumstance?

Comment: I doubt it. Not if only one person raises the issue. They would probably respond with their reasons for the policy without further discussion.

Answer (score 7):

For most journals the "Editorial Board" is not expected to jointly decide on anything. Papers get an editor assigned and it is more likely than not that other Editorial Board members are only interested in the papers they get assigned but wouldn't care about what happens to other papers. I am Editorial Board member myself. This is because I was invited, they're happy to have my name there and that I do some work for the journal. However I'm not all too committed to the journals for which I'm on the EB and to decisions that somebody else makes there. Most likely I'd ignore an email like the one you're asking about (I may drop a single line that I'm not expert for the paper in question or that I don't have time to take this on with the editor who made the decision). Even in the unlikely but possible case that your paper makes me curious and I have a quick look, the very best you could expect from me is "sorry but that's not up to me to decide; I think your paper is nice, so I recommend to try another journal".

However I may of course also think that the editor was right rejecting it.

Comment: But what if this inquiry does not say anything to you about which paper it is or what it's about?

Comment: Your answer raises the question: Which authority promulgated this policy? Is it the editor-in-chief alone? Or some body consisting of more than one person? (I imagine this could vary from one journal to another.)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "promulgated". In general, all power rests with the editor, and they can do, more or less, as they wish, gross misconduct/illegality aside. I suspect the policy was decided by the editor-in-chief, and will be enforce by whoever spots that your paper is a resubmission, might be the handling editor, might be someone else. You might get lucky and noone might notice that its a resubmission (although its unlikely).

Comment: @Michael Hardy (first question; second is addressed appropriately by Ian Sudbery): If the inquiry doesn't say anything about the paper, how can I assess whether the editor's comments are wrong or inappropriate? You haven't given us the full comment of the editor, but even if the editor writes just one sentence, it is conceivable (without knowing the paper) that the comment contains the key of why the paper is unacceptable, even if I may find it too brief. Editors are not obliged to write something detailed when rejecting.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: By the way, I do agree with the sentiment that there may be a lack of accountability in this situation, which is not necessarily healthy for science. But this would lead to a far more general discussion that indeed some people have. Criticism of the current journal publication system is easy to find and to agree with, coming up with better alternatives is much harder (particularly because it is not so easy to find enough highly qualified people who put their time that they may otherwise use for their own research into running journals).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen. Just waste of time and likely upsetting yourself (or upsetting yourself more in case you were upset already) and others. As it happens to me answering this.

Now the question is edited so I guess you can change vote.

(I am a chemist and my interests are the chemistry and physics of organic molecules as materials)

Comment: You call it "highly formal." That to me suggests there are probably both codified rules and conventional rules involved. Where would one find out about those? Could it be that what you say applies in some academic fields and is unknown in others? Which fields did you have in mind?

Comment: I am in hard science. But my answer was intended to clarify that one *doesn't argue with journals/editors*. I thought to have emphasised that, and pointed you to submit elsewhere option. In fact, the rebuttal is codified somewhere in the journal or publisher rules. It is really something to be done if your research/results is a point of force and for unfortunate circumstances that force went unnoticed (genuinely or by other reasons). Don't do that.

Comment: I know of nothing corresponding to "codified somewhere in the journal or publisher rules" except the usual "information for authors" section, where I haven't seen anything about this. Can you cite an example, with a link, to such a codification? "Hard science" is quite broad, so I'm suspecting you're in some field in which such a thing exists but that it does not in others. Physics? Chemistry? Astronomy? Materials science? Geology?

Comment: ok, Looking around the web a but, I see that this is in fact a thing in some academic fields, but it is altogether a different thing from what this is about.

Comment: I now regret having up-voted this answer. It turns out that (1) In some fields, a certain activity is called "rebuttal", and (2) in other fields that activity exists but that word for it is unknown, and (3) it has nothing at all to do with this situation. This answer is nonsense.

Comment: Your attitude is that of arguing. That explains the type of question you come up to and with. I even don't understand now what I spent minutes answering it. Except you are asking if you shall suggest a different editorial policy independently of your rejected paper... Perhaps I did not get this point. If it is, I think is not your business, not in fashion you suggested.

Comment: @MichaelHardy for instance I've sent a formal letter with logos and digital signature and explicitly said that we were asking for a rebuttal procedures of the first outcome. Followed by a detailed document framing our research and dismantling point by point the referees criticisms. It is nothing like a standard answer to the referees. This might be unrelated,;it is just to finish the above discussion. The final result was positive, for the chronicles.

Comment: "Your attitude is that of arguing." But only because you posted a wildly incorrect answer. The "rebuttal" process about which you write has nothing to do with the situation we're talking about, and in fact the very term "rebuttal" in the particular sense in which you use it is unknown in my field (although the process is not).

Comment: What I can do is to delete my answer. The answer to your actual question is "nothing will happen".At first I've taken this to mean that you wanted to reverse the assessment on your paper based on supposedly malicious practice by the referees. In reality it hard to understand what you are thinking about. Their policy obviously assume genuine reviewing processes. The real step would be to demonstrate that they were not.

Comment: I never said it was malicious; I said it was dishonest.